# My leopard gecko has a huge issue

Tags: health, eating, leopard-geckos

My male leopard gecko is not eating, and hasn’t been. The vet told us they did not see anything wrong but, we are very worried about him. He is getting red spots all over his body. HELP! He is eating a paste given to us by the vet. It gives him all the nutrients he needs while he won’t eat. We have to force feed him. He is supposed to love it, but he hates it. He has a lot of space, the tank is about 2 and 1/2 feet long, and 1 and a 1/2 feet wide. The temperature is about 80 degrees Fahrenheit. We have not changed calcium powders recently and I will add pictures in a few hours. Thankyou so much for your help! 
https://share.icloud.com/photos/0l4SeFrOngB1o5--BCBCXeMEg
https://share.icloud.com/photos/06GsC8ttvEuYae_26cVwIL9fA

Answer (score 1):

I kept a leopard gecko (and snakes and bearded dragons) for many years around two decades ago. When you took him to the vet, did she do a fecal screen to check for parasites? There are parasites which can cause this and similar symptoms.

More importantly, leopard geckos live in dry rocky desert areas and they get warmth by sitting/laying on top of warm rocks. They need a basking spot or warm area with a temperature around 90° with the ability to get to a cooler end of the terrarium to be able to regulate body temperature. If your terrarium is always at 80° there is no way for your gecko to do that and it won't be able to properly digest its food, which could be why it isn't eating willingly. In your picture of the terrarium, the lights are over plants and there are no visible basking places. The best thing would be to add a flat rock or something for the lizard to easily be able to climb onto and bask under. An under tank heater is also another good option to provide a low to the ground hot area for your gecko.